# How to get the image from the resource using ILSpy

Tags: dll, ilspy

I don't know it is a valid question or not.
But,
I am bit curious about How do I get the Image or icon in the resource of any`dll`.

Can any one tell me how do I do that?

I am using a `dll` where there are many icons in the resource.

Comment: A .NET decompiler is not suitable to handle "any dll".  Most DLLs store images and icons in the .rsrc section of the file.  Simplest way to get them out is by using Visual Studio (not Express), File + Open + File.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry not clear can you explain?